# Does OpenMP use reuse threads of completed section for another one?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Suppose I've got OpenMP setup for running multiple sections as below:

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
  #pragma omp section
  { func a }
  #pragma omp section
  { func b }
}
```

Now suppose *func b* has finished first while *func a* is still running. Does OpenMP use the threads that were used in *func a* to further parallelize *func b*? If not, is there a way to do that?

**Edit:** It's been suggested in a previous question that the threads that were previously used remains idle. Would there be a way to get them to work on a still running section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does OpenMP reuse threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572043/how-does-openmp-reuse-threads)

Comment: I've taken a look at that. The answer says that the threads remain idle. My question is if there is a way to put them to use in the still running section.

Comment: @StaticCrazee How should OpenMP utilize the thread from section a? Last time I checked the spec, there was supposed to be at-most one thread per section!

The only way of reusing a thread I could come up with, would require a nowait-clause on the sections (+ a broader parallel-block)...

Comment: Unless you have some nested parallelism further down in functions `a` & `b` and nested parallelism has been enabled, each section is executed by a single thread. Idle threads will not "help parallelize" because sections are serial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP does not use an idle thread to further parallelize the other `section` in your code.  If you want better load balancing between the threads, then you would have to use a more modern OpenMP programming style that relies on OpenMP tasks.  Ready-to-execute tasks are picked up by idle threads automatically when the thread becomes idle.

So, the code then would look more like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel master
{
  #pragma omp task
  { func a }  // func a needs to generate more tasks 
  #pragma omp task
  { func b }  // func b needs to generate more tasks 
}
```

Comment: I would add to that answer, that both tasks must individually spawn more child tasks in order to actually exploit load balancing.

Comment: @Zulan: that's right. A typical ratio is to have about 10 times more tasks than threads. That usually gives enough work for load balancing. Another threshold depends on the amount of work per task. That threshold depends on the implementation, but for OpenMP this is usually about 100k processor cycles.